# How get the document with minimum value in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have some documents like these:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "type" : "A", "price" : 10, "name" : "A1"}
{ "_id" : 2, "type" : "A", "price" : 30, "name" : "A2"}
{ "_id" : 3, "type" : "A", "price" : 20, "name" : "A3"}
{ "_id" : 4, "type" : "B", "price" : 15, "name" : "B1"}
{ "_id" : 5, "type" : "B", "price" : 25, "name" : "B2"}
{ "_id" : 6, "type" : "B", "price" : 5, "name" : "B3"}
{ "_id" : 7, "type" : "C", "price" : 30, "name" : "C1"}
{ "_id" : 8, "type" : "C", "price" : 20, "name" : "C2"}
```

I want to find the document (whole fields including "**name**") with minimum price value per each "type", like as:

```
{ "type" : "A", "price" : 10, "name" : "A1"}
{ "type" : "B", "price" : 5, "name" : "B3"}
{ "type" : "C", "price" : 20, "name" : "C2"}
```

Is there any idea how I can write a MongoDB query?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$sort` before `$group`,

- `$sort` by price ascending order
- `$group` by type and add first record in all fields

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $sort: { price: 1 } },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$type",
      name: { $first: "$name" },
      price: { $first: "$price" }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/13B8K45UWvU)

Comment: Thanks a lot @turivishal.  It works. Is there more efficient way?

Comment: @AsefPourmasoomi You can create an index on the price field. So that $sort stage can use the index. ```db.collection.createIndex({"price":1})```

Answer (score -1):

Instead You can try this.

```
 db.collection.aggregate([
     {
       $group:
         {
           _id: "$type",
            name: { $first: "$name" },
           price: { $min: "$price" }
         }
     }
   ])
```